# how to sort lines of a file in c by looking one of the attributes in the line?

Tags: c, file, sorting

In my example, one line includes 8 attributes (as strings and integers) which are separated by commas (`,`). I split these attributes according to the commas and I have a condition as: *print the lines in the file which have the same country name (one of the attributes) with the input that user entered.* So I wrote this using `strcasecmp` (to compare two string case insensitively):

```
if (strcasecmp(enteredCountryName, CountryNameInTheFile) == 0) {
    fputs(line, outpufile);
}
```

But I want to put the lines into the output file in an ascending alphabetic order due to the city names which are another attribute. I have always seen similar examples on the Internet like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (strcmp(name[i], name[j]) > 0) {
            strcpy(temp, name[i]);
            strcpy(name[i], name[j]);
            strcpy(name[j], temp);
        }
    }
}
```

But I could not adapt them to my code since I'm a new learner. Can you show me how I can adapt it? Or if you have a different suggestion for sorting according to the condition that I told, I would love to hear it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should probably sort the strings in a case independent manner too. Please post a complete program and specify what is the problem. Code fragments are insufficient to get useful advice.

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes Can I ask a different question before that? For example, if the user enters a command like *, how can I print all lines? Since I use Codeblocks, I need to enter the command like "*" but then I cannot get the result that I want. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c, the easiest way to sort something is to use the built-in `qsort` functionality and supply a comparator for the items you need to sort.

The function definition can be seen (with examples) online here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort

For your code, the sorting option would look something like

```
qsort(name, n, strcmp)
```

then you can use any way you want to write them to your file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I ask another question? For example, I want to print all the lines in the file if the user enters a star character ( * ) as acommand. Since I use Codeblocks, I need to enter the command in quotes (" * ") but then I cannot get the result that I want. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: I don't know much about Codeblocks personally. That might need to be its own question :)

Answer (score 0):

You program must first ask the user for a country name and read this string into an array with `fgets()` or `scanf()`, using the proper conversion format depending if there are spaces in the name or not. If you use `fgets()`, make sure you strip the trailing newline.

Then the program opens the file and reads the lines one at a time.

You find the field and its length with `strchr()`.

You compare the field value with the user input, ignoring case. Don't use `strcasestr()` for this because it is non standard and would require that you null terminate the field.
Instead use a loop and compare the characters using `tolower()` to ignore the case.

If the field is a match, first print the line.

Once your program behaves correctly, you can implement the sort by storing copies of the lines in an array of strings and sort that with `qsort()`, then print the strings from the array.